# Value error inserting into Postgres table with psycopg2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, postgresql, psycopg2

I've been trying to use this piece of code:

```
# df is the dataframe
if len(df) > 0:
df_columns = list(df)
# create (col1,col2,...)
columns = ",".join(df_columns)

# create VALUES('%s', '%s",...) one '%s' per column
values = "VALUES({})".format(",".join(["%s" for _ in df_columns])) 

#create INSERT INTO table (columns) VALUES('%s',...)
insert_stmt = "INSERT INTO {} ({}) {}".format(table,columns,values)

cur = conn.cursor()
cur = db_conn.cursor()
psycopg2.extras.execute_batch(cur, insert_stmt, df.values)
conn.commit()
cur.close()
```

So I could connect into Postgres DB and insert values from a df.

I get these 2 errors for this code:

`LINE 1: INSERT INTO mrr.shipments (mainFreight_freight_motherVesselD...`

```
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column "mainfreight_freight_mothervesseldepartdatetime" of relation "shipments" does not exist
```

for some reason, the columns can't get the values properly

What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You should not do your own string interpolation; let psycopg2 handle it.  From [the docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html):

> Warning Never, never, NEVER use Python string concatenation (+) or string parameters interpolation (%) to pass variables to a SQL query string. Not even at gunpoint.

Since you also have dynamic column names, you should use [psycopg2.sql](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html) to create the statement and then use the standard method of passing query parameters to psycopg2 instead of using format.

Comment: It's actually working as is, I just needed to add parenthesis to it could read the columns properly in the 'Execute batch' command.

Comment: It may be working for now, but it's bad practice and it will break the first time one of the values contains a special character like a quote.